# Create new version is disabled in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am a new iTunesConnect user. I created a new version (with wrong version number) by mistake. Now this version is in - ready to prepare for submission state. Now I want to add a new version with a correct version number. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you've created a new version you can't create another new version until the first one has been approved. Instead, you should select your new version, scroll way down near the bottom of the page, then amend the version number you entered incorrectly. The field is just below the app icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. Saved a lot of my time.